# Best way to move power BI dataflows to Azure synapse

Tags: powerbi, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I am in the process of creating an enterprise operating model for Power BI and Azure Synapse.

I'm trying to see if there are any ways to move a power BI dataflow transformation to Azure Synapse. I'll give an example use-case:

- I build a dataflow transformation in Power BI, it is relatively complex with multiple steps involved.
- I want to then strengthen and productionise this transformation in the form of an ETL pipeline using Azure Synapse.

What is the best way to leverage as much of the effort put into the dataflow as possible?

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Also interested in this. I have a Power App backed by a set of Dataverse tables. The data from this app is being distributed to end users by a Dataflow that feeds a shared Excel. My aim is for transformed data to flow to the org Azure Synapse in its transformed state rather than having all the individual Dataverse tables be linked to Synapse via the Dataverse connector. Surely this can be achieved. Seems pointless to have to create an ADF pipeline duplicating the effort in the Dataflow.

Edit: This might be helpful to you - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/power-bi-dataflows-and-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-integration-preview/

CDM is the answer I believe.

Comment: Hi, if you encounter the same issue you can upvote the OP's question, answers are meant to provide help. If you have a different issue, you can also create your own question with more details. Also avoid link-only answers; directly quote the helpful part of the article instead so that your answer is still relevant if the link becomes unavailable.